# Find the smallest number that satisfies the condition

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the smallest $\alpha$ such that $\forall x \in R^n : x^TAx + \alpha||x||^2 \geq 0$ (dot product is euclidean) where $$ 
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & -2 & 1 \\
-2 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
I tried: 
Let $ x=(a,b,c) $
$$x^TAx + \alpha||x||^2 {= x^TAx + \alpha x^T x = x^T(A+ \alpha I)x \\= (a+ \alpha a + b -2c, a-2b+ \alpha b +c, 2a+b+c+ \alpha c)^T * (a,b,c) \\= a^2 + \alpha a^2 - 2c + \alpha b^2 +2bc + 2ac +c^2 + \alpha c^2 \geq0}$$

Questions:

1. How can I get to the answer? And, perhaps, there should an easier way to solve it.
2. What does $\alpha$ represent? I think that it is the smallest distance we should move each vector so $x^TAx\ge0$. Am I right?

Comment: $\alpha$ is the norm of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $x^T(A+\alpha I)x=x^T(0.5A^T+0.5A+\alpha I)x$. Hence, we are looking for the smallest value of $\alpha$ for which, $0.5A^T+0.5A+\alpha I$ is positive semi-definite. The eigenvalues of $0.5A^T+0.5A$ can be simply calculated as
$$
\lambda_1=1\quad,\quad \lambda_2=\frac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{2}\quad,\quad \lambda_2=\frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{2}.
$$
Therefore, $\alpha=-\min_i\lambda_i=\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}$.